# Unable to destroy activity... java.lang.NullPointerException: observer

Tags: android

I'm hoping someone could help me here. I can't seem to track down what is causing this. I am testing Firebase messaging. onMessageReceived is successfully hit, yet I get this error when I call NotificationManager.notify:

> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy
>   activity {com.myproject.android/com.myproject.android.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: observer

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
                RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
                createNotification(notification);
        }
    }



private void createNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notification) {
    Context context = getBaseContext();
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContentText(notification.getBody());
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I had some code in my MainActivity onDestroy that shouldn't have been there. The error threw me off because I have no idea why my MainActivity onDestroy is being called here.